# How do I close database connections in a JBOSS application with a hibernate datasource?

Tags: spring, hibernate, database-connection, jboss7.x, connection-pooling

I maintain a JBOSS-9/Spring-4/Hibernate-4 application which apparently fails to close/release any database connections. Whatever size I set my database connection pool, once that many users connect to our server and make a request, the pool runs out of connections and any further requests fail due to the server being unable to make any new database connection.

I have followed the suggestions from this post:
[Cached connection manager in jboss/wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365722/cached-connection-manager-in-jboss-wildfly)

When I enable the cached connection manager (use-ccm="true") turn on debug (debug="true"), and increase the log level to DEBUG, I see messages that indicate that with that configuration, my connections are indeed released. When I turn off the cached connection manager, I start running out of connections again. Despite the recommendation from the link above, is there any reason why I shouldn't just enable the cached connection manager full time?

Since the application's Java code never explicitly opens a connection (it just implicitly uses a dataSource bean via a Hibernate session), I didn't believe that the code needed to do anything explicit to close a connection.

Thanks for any input to help me resolve this issue.

For the record, here is my datasource configuration in standalone.xml:

```
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dct-service-db" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dct</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                <pool>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name/>
                    <password/>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
```

Here is some of my spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/dct-service-db"/>
 </bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.hmhco.dct.entity.District</value>
            <!--value>...</value-->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Finally - here is some of BaseDAO.java which manages the sessionFactory property and uses it to access the datasource:

```
public class BaseDAO {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BaseDAO.class);

protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public BaseEntity findById(Class entityClass, Integer id) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(entityClass);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    BaseEntity entity = (BaseEntity) crit.uniqueResult();
    if (entity != null) {
      entity.setLastAccessed(new Date());
      session.update(entity);
    }
    session.close();
    return entity;
 }
```

Let me know if this is enough information to help diagnose the problem - or if you want/need more.

I did just find this information on a hibernate page: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite rudimentary.
> It is intended to help you get started and is not intended for use in a
> production system, or even for performance testing. You should use a third
> party pool for best performance and stability. Just replace the
> hibernate.connection.pool_size property with connection pool
> specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's internal pool.
> For example, you might like to use c3p0.
>
> C3P0 is an open source JDBC connection pool distributed along with Hibernate
> in the lib directory. Hibernate will use its
> org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider for connection pooling
> if you set hibernate.c3p0.* properties

Comment: can you post some of your code? spring configuration, or an example of you making a query, calling a procedure, or reading a resultset?  it would be helpful.

Comment: You can check with your database team as they can also track connections and tell you when connection was started and it is in idle or waiting state. This will give you an overview which workflow is causing connection leak issue.

Comment: I am the one and only developer on this project (i.e. there is no separate database team). I have not written a JBOSS/Hibernate app before, so I don't know how it is supposed to be configured. I followed the documentation referenced above which claimed I wasn't leaking any connections (after changing my configuration to use the cached connection manager).