# How can I identify connection leaks in wildlfly server

Tags: jboss, database-connection, jboss7.x, amazon-aurora, wildfly-22

My wildfly server loses connection to database very frequently. How can I identify connection leaks to database. My application stops working after losing connection to database and not able to reconnect again. I need to restart again. Please suggest any way to identify the leaks. Thanks in advance for help.

I have tried using cache connection manager and reading jmx console values of active count etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cached Connection Manager (ccm) with `debug="true"`, e.g.

```xml
<cached-connection-manager debug="true" />
```

Should make it so that WildFly/JBoss should close connections for you and log a stacktrace in the server log each time it does, telling you exactly where in your connection leak is when that code path is executed.

Here are a few references:

- [Red Hat Solutions - How to detect leaked datasource connections using the cached connection manager (CCM) debug facility in JBoss EAP](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/309913)
- [StackOverflow - Cached connection manager in jboss/wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365722/cached-connection-manager-in-jboss-wildfly)